# Sails.JS file upload - can't get a file on req.file()

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I've just begun using Sails.JS and I tried to make a simple file upload. In Sails.JS, I've done this:

```js
uploadFile: (req, res) => {
  req.file('avatar').upload({
   dirname: '../../assets/uploads'
  }, function (err, uploadedFiles){
   if (err) return res.serverError(err);
   return res.json({
    message: uploadedFiles.length + ' file(s) uploaded successfully!',
    files: uploadedFiles
   });
  });
 }
```

For Postman, I've done this:
[image: upload file via postman]

The problem is, after I upload a file via Postman, I don't get a file in req.file(). However, console.log(req) does show my uploaded file's binary (or something like that). I just can't figure out what happened.

Comment: Can you post the source code of the http request performed into the frontend please? Also note that as mentioned in [Sails Documentation](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/request-req/req-file) "...Text parameters must be included before files in the request body..."

Comment: I only sent the request by postman and I tried to add some text parameters but it still does not work. I am not sure about the meaning of text parameters so I update the postman picture above.

Comment: Can you try by changing it to `dirname: require('path').resolve('../../assets/uploads')` ?

Comment: Can you try with 
```dirname: require('path').resolve(sails.config.appPath, 'assets/uploads')```
and make sure that this folder already exist